# A holomorphic function in an open disc has a primitive in that disc

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I am referring to the proof given in Stein's textbook on complex analysis. 
He assumes the disk is centered at the origin and given a point $z$ in this disk, he considers the polygonal line $\gamma_z$ that joins $0$ to $z$, first by moving horizontally from $0$ to Re($z$), then vertically from Re($z$) to z. It consists of (at most) 2 segments. Then, he defines 
$$F(z) = \int_{\gamma_z} f(w)dw.$$

The point I can't understand is the following: "The choice of $\gamma_z$ gives an unambiguous definition of the function $F (z)$. I understood the remainder of the proof. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Probably he wants to say that $F(z)$ is well defined for all $z$ in the disc.

Comment: For me that means that the fact that you chose a precise $\gamma_z$  makes $F(z)$ well-defined (at least as a function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, one might define $$F(z) := \int_{\eta_z} f(w) \,dw ,$$ where $\eta_z$ is *any* curve in the disc $\Bbb D$ from $0$ to $z$, but in order for this to be well-defined, we'd need to check that the integral doesn't depend on the choice of $\eta_z$. (It turns out that this is the case, since $\Bbb D$ is simply connected and $f$ is holomorphic, the Cauchy Integral Formula implies that the definitions actually coincide.) Specifying for each $z \in \Bbb D$ a unique path means that there are no choices to be made in our definition, which means that $F(z)$ is automatically well-defined.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering though, is there an way to prove that $F$ is well defined without using the argument that the disk a simply connected space? Because this proof is later used to prove that the integrals over homotopic curves are equal, and it would be somewhat contradictory

Comment: Simple-connectedness is necessary. For example, consider $f(z) := \frac{1}{z}$, which is holomorphic on $D := \Bbb C - \{ 0 \}$, and fix our starting point to be $1$. Then, if $c_1 : [0, 1]\to D$ is the constant curve $c_1(t):=1$ and $\gamma:[0,1] \to D$ is the circular curve $\gamma(t) := \exp(2\pi it)$, we see that both curves end at $1$ but you can compute yourself that $\int_{c_1}\frac{dz}{z}=0\neq 2\pi i = \int_{\gamma}\frac{dz}{z}$. In fact, this example gives rise to the necessity of choosing branch cuts when working with the complex logarithm. NB $c_1$ and $\gamma$ are *not* homotopic.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Cheers, I'm glad you found it useful.

Comment: I'm sorry to botther you, but I might have another question: by which means does the Cauchy Integral Formula imply the coincidence of the two definitions?

Comment: Given two paths from $a$ to $b$, we can reverse the direction of one, and then concatenating them will give a loop (closed path). The CIF gives that the integral over the loop is zero, and writing that integral in terms of the two paths and rearranging shows that the values of the path integrals along those paths agree.